# How can I fix "Cannot convert system.generic.list to model"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My error message is: "cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List to Model"

[image: error message]

Below code is my model:

```cs
public class PatientDemographicsandAddressModel
{
     public List<PhoneAddressModel> PhoneAddressModel { get; set; }
}
```

And this where I'm trying to use this List. And error comes in this code:

```cs
if (patientDemographics.PhoneAddressModel.Count > 0)
{
    patientId = patientDemographics.Id;
    // List<PhoneAddressModel> phoneAddressModel = patientDemographics.PhoneAddressModel;
    var phoneAddressModel = patientDemographics.PhoneAddressModel;
    _iPatientPhoneAddressService.SavePhoneAddress(patientId, phoneAddressModel, token, request);
}
```

And this is the service that I'm trying to reuse:

```cs
public JsonModel SavePhoneAddress(int patientId, PhoneAddressModel phoneAddressModel, TokenModel tokenModel,HttpRequest request)
{
    ...
}
```

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: One is a list the other is a single item in a list. You could only assign one (or cast one), eg `PhoneAddressModel[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to supply a List instead of a single class object to your `_iPatientPhoneAddressService.SavePhoneAddress(patientId, phoneAddressModel, token, request)`
method. Your `phoneAddressModel` parameter is a `PhoneAddressModel`, not a `List<PhoneAddressModel>`.

Instead, try iterating over your list, calling your service method each time:

```cs
if (patientDemographics.PhoneAddressModel.Count > 0)
{  
   patientId = patientDemographics.Id;

   foreach (PhoneAddressModel model in patientDemographics.PhoneAddressModel)
   { 
      _iPatientPhoneAddressService.SavePhoneAddress(patientId, model, token, request);
   }
}
```